# Debugger skipping methods after organizing code into new solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, methods

I had a perfectly working API that was making http calls & a UI that was using that API.

Everything was working and it was built really ugly ( 2 solutions for everything), so I wanted to separate everything so it would be more organized.

- UI
- DataManagerService
- DataManager
- Contracts

After a lot of copy paste & dependencies references it all looked like its working with 0 errors.

BUT now something weird happens, A method is being skipped and I have NO IDEA WHY.
I am not on release mode.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it!

The method that is being skipped :

```
private static List<Actor> ReadActorsFromJson(string json)
{
            List<Actor> celebListReadFromFile;

            try
            {
                var celebJson = File.ReadAllText(json);
                celebListReadFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Actor>>(celebJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                celebListReadFromFile = new List<Actor>();
                // Empty list/whatever it got in it
            }

            return celebListReadFromFile;
}
```

Which is being invoked by :

```
public static async Task SaveOriginal()
{
    foreach (var currceleb in ReadActorsFromJson(filePath))
    {
        var curr = currceleb;
        originalList.TryAdd(currceleb.name, currceleb);
    }
}
```

and this method is being invoked by the classes static constructor:

```
static Logic()
{
        originalList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Actor>();
        filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempList"];
        File.Copy(filePath, BACKUP, true);

        // invoking the method 
        SaveOriginal();
}
```

The API:

```
using Contracts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication12.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        public ILogic _Ilogic;

        public ValuesController(ILogic logic)
        {
            _Ilogic = logic;
        }

        // GET api/values
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetActors()
        {
            return Json(await _Ilogic.GetAllActorsAsync(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveActorAsync(Actor actor) {
            await _Ilogic.RemoveActorAsync(actor.name);
            return Json(await _Ilogic.GetAllActorsAsync());
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetAsync()
        {
            await _Ilogic.ResetAsync();
            return Json(await _Ilogic.GetAllActorsAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

The business logic :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Contracts;

namespace DataManager
{
    public class Logic : ILogic
    {
        static string filePath;
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Actor> originalList;
        const string BACKUP = @"C:\tempList\backup.txt";

        static Logic()
        {
            originalList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Actor>();
            filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempList"];
            File.Copy(filePath, BACKUP, true);

            SaveOriginal();
        }

        public async static Task<List<Actor>> GetCelebritiesInner()
        {
            return originalList.Values.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<List<Actor>> GetAllActorsAsync()
        {
            return await GetCelebritiesInner();
        }

        // Try to read the data from the Json and initialize it. if failed , initialize with whatever it got. return 
        private static List<Actor> ReadActorsFromJson(string json)
        {
            List<Actor> celebListReadFromFile;

            try
            {
                var celebJson = File.ReadAllText(json);
                celebListReadFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Actor>>(celebJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                celebListReadFromFile = new List<Actor>();
                // Empty list/whatever it got in it
            }

            return celebListReadFromFile;
        }

        public async Task RemoveActorAsync(string name)
        {
            if (originalList.TryRemove(name, out Actor removedActor))
            {
                var jsonToWrite = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await GetCelebritiesInner());

                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonToWrite);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Unable to remove due to an error.
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task ResetAsync()
        {
            originalList.Clear();
            await UpdateFile();
            await SaveOriginal();
        }

        //Saving the actor, adding the name as key & object as value.
        public static async Task SaveOriginal()
        {
            foreach (var currceleb in ReadActorsFromJson(filePath))
            {
                var curr = currceleb;
                originalList.TryAdd(currceleb.name, currceleb);
            }
        }

        public static async Task UpdateFile()
        {
            File.Copy(BACKUP, filePath, true);
        }
    }
}
```

When running the program, the static ctor is being invoked and should invoke the SaveOriginal method. which it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried to Clean and Rebuild the solution?

Comment: How did you conclude it is not invoked? Also, `SaveOriginal` is a `Task` and could be executed outside of your debugger context, so it might look like it is not executed, because maybe your debugger is unable to step in. Have you tried logging inside a `ContinueWith` continuation action? `SaveOriginal().ContinueWith(_ => Log());`

Comment: Furthermore: Executing an async Task like that from a static constructor is, in my opinion, a bad idea, because you have no control over it.

Comment: Ok I solved it....NO IDEA why it takes 2 days & a Stackoverflow post to find the problem. lol posting the answer and process of finding the error right now

Comment: Silvermind could you please explain \ give me a source to why executing an async Task from a static ctor is bad?

Comment: @RomanSterlin If you want me to receive a message you should address my alias with an `@` symbol. Anyway... Constructors cannot be async and should be light weight. It is only meant for simple initialization. You are not awaiting the operation to complete, but somehow it needs to be loaded and you never know for certain when the class is actually accessed, hence you do not have real control over it. Some day you access it somewhere earlier and you suddenly experience side-effects. Make the operation part of a initialization process you initiate manually and not part of a static constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Static constructor calls when the first access is made. You are using dependency injection which is lazy loading. It doesn't create object until first access is made.
So, Try to get/set any property or method, static constructor will be called first.

Comment: Hey thanks Chanchal, but the UI actually does create an object becuase the UI has an update() method that is being invoked as soon as the UI starts ,making a http request to a method inside the logic Class with the static ctor

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I cleaned and re built every solution one by one ( I don't know if it helped) & then I ran the API, sent a request from POSTMAN instead of opening the UI, in postman I got the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies
```

I looked at the versions in the Nuget packages and there was no 12.0.0.0 in there, so I removed Newtonsoft.Json from all solutions, re-installed Newtonsoft.Json in every solution and it worked.
turns out somehow when opening the new solutions, I installed different Newtonsoft.Json versions. and this caused the program to skip the method without giving the stack trace like postman did, weird.